# How can I import a custom map into Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've watched lots of Minecraft videos on YouTube, where they tell you to "extract the Minecraft map", but none of them explain exactly what I need to do to get that map imported into Minecraft, once I've downloaded it.

What exactly do I need to do to get a custom map available within the game?

I'm using Windows 10 and Minecraft version 1.8.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, follow along with me:

1. Go to the downloaded map or whatever, and if you have it in a .ZIP file extract it using WinRAR to a specified folder (I would recommend your documents folder). If you don't then go to the folder where the file was downloaded too, and continue on
2. Cut the extracted file
3. Go to your search bar, and type in run. Click the application "Run", and inside of run type in %appdata%
4. Open up the folder called .minecraft
5. Inside of that folder, open up the folder called saves
6. Paste the file you cut in the beginning into that folder

Boom! You are done!

**EDIT**: JonK posted this method:

1. Follow the first two steps above
2. Open up the current Minecraft Launcher
3. Go to the Edit Profiles Button
4. Select Open Game Dir
5. Then go into saves
6. Paste the file

Comment: There's another way to get to the saves directory: in the Minecraft Launcher hit Edit Profile, then select Open Game Dir. That takes you directly to the `.minecraft` folder in AppData, from there, just double-click on the saves directory.

Comment: It does? I didn't know that! Thanks JonK!

Comment: I've already upvoted, but I think if you include that as an alternative method it'd make this an even better answer.

Comment: Done! I did your suggestion!

Comment: but i dont know how to extract

Comment: @maxdude2074 Right click the .ZIP then select 'Extract all'

Comment: @maxdude2074 If this answer solved your problem please click the check mark below the score to accept the answer

Comment: @angussidney it doeset say extract file

Comment: @ModDL  i know that

Comment: @maxdude2074 Look at this: http://www.simplehow.tips/a/56/how-to-zip-and-unzip-files-in-windows10

Comment: God help this child. @maxdudr2074

Comment: @TheVoidChaos Now i know how to extract files. This question was made a long time ago.

Comment: @JonK does that work on platforms other than Windows, too? Because the original answer only explains how to get to the folder in Windows, not on a Mac/Linux. (In which, I believe, it's located at `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`)

Comment: @Plagiatus It *should* do, I can't imagine Mojang would leave that route broken on Unix-based operating systems. I don't have access to such a system to confirm it though.