# How can I transfer my Minecraft world from one computer to another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a Minecraft world that I have been playing on for a while, and I would like to transfer it to a new computer. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how can I go about it? Can you help me out? Any guidance or tips on transferring a Minecraft world from one computer to another would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find your Minecraft saves in the following locations, depending on your Operating System:

Windows: `%appdata%\.minecraft\saves\`
GNU/Linux: `~/.minecraft/saves/`
Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/`

These locations assume you are using the vanilla launcher. If you're using a custom launcher (such as FTBApp, Curseforge, MultiMC, etc.), they can be located anywhere (consult your launcher's instance configuration).

Each additional folder in there is essentially a world.

---

As for transfering them, you just copy the individual folders in the `saves` folder somewhere, and just copy it back to the same location on your other computer.

[image]

[Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236251/how-can-i-import-a-custom-map-into-minecraft)